# how to extract a specific field?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows

```
pd.DataFrame({'normalvar':1, 'weirdo': [{'Item': [{'basket': 'Text', 'Value': 'Stackoverflow'}]}]})

    
Out[68]: 
   normalvar                                                    weirdo
0          1  {'Item': [{'basket': 'Text', 'Value': 'Stackoverflow'}]}
```

The variable `weirdo` comes from some parsed `json` material.

I would like to create a column `myextraction` that just contains the value of `Value` (whenever possible): that is `Stackoverflow`

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Is your dataframe composed of several rows? and has the list in weirdo always have at least one dictionary in it? and does the dictionary always has the key Value in it?

Comment: yes, many rows. but value may be missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df['myextraction'] = df['weirdo'][0]['Item'][0]['Value']
        
>>> df
        
   normalvar                                             weirdo   myextraction
0          1  {'Item': [{'basket': 'Text', 'Value': 'Stackov...  Stackoverflow
```

Comment: apologies, the variable was a bit more nested. example updated ...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['myextraction'] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(np.array(df.weirdo.values.tolist()).ravel(),
                                               index=df.index)['Value']
```

Output:

```
       normalvar                                         weirdo   myextraction
Item           1  [{'basket': 'one', 'Value': 'Stackoverflow'}]  Stackoverflow
Item2          1             [{'basket': 'two', 'Value': 'SO'}]             SO
```

Comment: apologies, the variable was a bit more nested. example updated ...